# How would I ignore faulty data sent via websocket.. in this case I'm trying to prevent string data from being accepted and used

Tags: c#, websocket, tcp

Here, I'm receving single stream of bytes 'data' from the client. I would like the server to only consider float values and handle string values differently

i.e. store string value in a different variable to be used elsewhere, and ignore the value just received, since the 'data' variable is used elsehwere to make important caluclation in real time..

```
try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);

        // Start listening for connections.
        while (true)
        {
            keepReading = true;

            // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Connection");     

            handler = listener.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");     

            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
            while (keepReading)
            {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received from Client");

                if (bytesRec <= 0)
                {
                    keepReading = false;
                    handler.Disconnect(true);
                    break;
                }

                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec); //get data from client
                is_float = float.TryParse(data, out float a);
                if (is_float == false) //trying to ignore anything not float
                {
                    //what to do here??
                     continue;
                }

                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before the  while loop: `var strings = new List<string>();`. in the loop: `if (!is_float) { strings.Add(data); }`. A question which arises is whether the `data` chunks contain a string with exactly one float. The `float.TryParse` method will only succeed if the `data` string starts with a float and contains only a float.

Comment: each time data is sent, it sends the float value and a flag string if needed.. the float value is needed to do calculations, while the string is used to perform another operation.. unfortunately, i'm in  a position where I need to use a single server  and single stream of info from the client.. i considered using another client handle the string, but that would'nt be suitable for my end goals..

Comment: Your question is currently too vague to answer properly. Could you describe in more detail how the client and server are expected to interact? This should include examples of what happens when the client disconnects, examples of the data it sends, and how it disconnects.

Comment: the client is an application that sends a float and string value over a single stream.. i'd like the server to handle such that it separates the two properly and use the data depending on the values received. If it's a float, do ABC, if it's a string, ignore the value if wrong or store in a separate variable if it's the correct string, and don't share the current received data with the rest of the program